# Android tabbar, which active item overlaps adjacent items (see image)

Tags: android, tabbar, overlapping

I need to make tabbar of the following desigh:
[image]

Its active item overlaps adjacent items.
My problem is that I don't know how to make different tabs overlap each other (as far as I know, it isn't possible to change z-order of views programmatically). How to do it?

P.S. By the way, that is not necessary for me to use particularly tabbar. That can be, for example, 3 buttons in horizontal linear layout or any other combination of views which allows to make tabbar functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this one by creating 3 buttons with rounded angles, big container with rounded angles (only top of it is displayed on my image) and linear layout behing above mentioned views, which fills space between bottom angles of any 2 adjacent buttons.

This linear layout consists of 4 parts which change its background color to appropriate one dynamically in buttons' onclicklistener (same for 3 buttons).

Shadows are implemented via gradient of black (with different alpha) in button's background drawables (which are layer-list with 3 shape items - background shape, padded shadow shape and again padded background shape).

Comment: Occasionally, I noticed View.bringToFront() method, which makes system render the view above other views. Probably, I could make 3 horizontal overlapping buttons and solve my issue by invoking button.bringToFront() in button's onclick listener. Besides, I would require to change background color of all the buttons in each onclicklistener. Actually, it looks easier than my initial solution, but I have never tested View.bringToFront().